# Wordpress insert category name into shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have created a wordpress shortcode to display documents, this works fine without any errors - see below

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[Documents category="books"]'); ?>
```

I'd like for the post category name to automatically be inserted into the shortcode, maybe something like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[Documents category="'. get_the_category( $id )[0]->name .' "]'); ?>
```

I don't get any errors, but the shortcode doesn't display anything, but does when if I actually type in the name.

I also tried this, but its showing all categories in the specified post type:

```
    <?php if( get_field('documents') == 'yes' ): ?> 
    <?php 
    $catname = $category->cat_name;
    $shortcode = '[Documents category="'.$catname.'"]';
    $to_string = strval($shortcode);
    echo do_shortcode($to_string);
    ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thought I had it resolved, but still nothing..